# how to make a subview fixed when transform it's parent view

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm using tranform to expand a button's size when it was tapped.
but the text component inside also changes it's size .how to fix it?

[image]

Here is my code:

```
 <TouchableHighlight
                        onPress={()=>{
                            if (this.state.isDeleting) {
                                this._deleteItem(index);                                    
                            }else {
                                this._expandDeleteButton();
                            }
                        }}
                        >
                        <Animated.View
                                style={[styles.deleteButton,{transform:[
                                    {
                                        scaleX:this.deleteButtonWidthScale.interpolate({
                                        inputRange: [0, 1],
                                        outputRange: [1, 2]
                                        })
                                    },
                                    {
                                        scaleY: this.deleteButtonWidthScale.interpolate({
                                            inputRange: [0, 1],
                                            outputRange: [1, 1]
                                        })
                                    },
                                    {
                                        translateX: this.deleteButtonWidthScale.interpolate({
                                            inputRange: [0, 1],
                                            outputRange: [0, -17.5]
                                        })
                                    },

                                    ]}]}>
                            <Text style={styles.deleteText}>{this.state.isDeleting?'确认删除':'删除'}</Text>
                        </Animated.View>
                    </TouchableHighlight>
```

Comment: deleteTextStyle is{color:"white", fontSize:17}

Comment: Fixed ,I put it in another VIEW

Answer (score 0):

Fixed ,I put it in another VIEW